# Módulo pygame problema en la instalacion

Tags: python, pygame

tengo un problema al instalar el módulo pygame , alguien podria ayudarme gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado solo usar  `pip install pygame` ? También, quizás no tengas la versión 3.8 de python, y has descargado la wheel para Python 3.8

Comment: muchas gracias , funciono, era mas simple de lo que parecia

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la versión que estás intentando instalar debe ser incompatible con tu python o con el SO (es de 64 bits?), prueba con la de 32 por si fuese eso.

Comment: no funciono con la de 32